# Troubleshooting nginx 302 redirection

Tags: nginx, subdomain, nginx-config, nginx-location, http-status-code-302

I have a server with nginx and wordpress docker containers.
Server domain: `my-blog.servername.com`.
Wordpress should be accessible in the subdirectory as `my-blog.servername.com/blog`.

I have another server with nginx set as `servername.com` and the problem is that nginx keep redirecting me to it even though it shouldn't.

sites-available/my-blog.servername.com.conf

```
server {
    listen *:80 default_server;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-blog.servername.com-access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/my-blog.servername.com-error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/security_headers.conf;

    client_max_body_size 32M;

    location / {
        return 302 https://my-blog.servername.com/blog/;
        #rewrite ^/$ /blog/ redirect;
    }


    # A solution based on https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-php-in-subdirectory
    location /blog {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/my-blog.servername.com-blog-access.log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/my-blog.servername.com-blog-error.log debug;

        # Serves static files directly and allows for friendly URLs
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        alias /var/www/sites/wpblog.servername.com;
        try_files $uri @blog;

        # Restrictions to favicon, robots.txt and hidden files (e.g. `.htaccess`, `.htpasswd`).
        location = /blog/favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off; access_log off;
        }

        location = /blog/robots.txt {
            allow all; log_not_found off; access_log off;
        }

        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
        }

        # Denies access to `.php` files in the uploads folder.
        # Works in subfolder installs and also in multisite network.
        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
            deny all;
        }

        # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
        location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
            access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
        }

        # Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
        # This is a robust solution for path info security issue and works
        # with "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1" in /etc/php.ini (default)
        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass my-blog:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                return 404;
            }
        }
    }

    location = /blog {
        return 302 https://my-blog.servername.com/blog/;
    }

    location = /blog/wp-admin {
        return 302 https://my-blog.servername.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php;
    }

    location = /blog/wp-admin/ {
        return 302 https://my-blog.servername.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php;
    }

    location @blog {
        rewrite /blog/(.*)$ /blog/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
}
```

The problem is that from `/var/log/nginx/my-blog.servername.com-blog-access.log` access logs I see that nginx is redirecting to the `servername.com/blog` instead of keeping it on the same server which is `my-blog.servername.com`.

Here is the access log record:

```
172.30.10.207 - - [08/Jul/2021:12:40:17 +0000]  302 "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 5 "https://servername.com/blog/en/" "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0" "{EXTERNAL-IP}"
```

I checked everywhere if there are wrong redirections, but haven't found anything. What am I missing?
Let me know if there is not enough info, I'd be happy to elaborate on things. Just don't want to unnecessarily overcomplicate this post.

Comment: Whats your site and homepage URL configured in wordpress? This is likely a WP managed Redirect.

Comment: @TimoStark I've set 'siteurl' in the db that WP is connected to behttps://my-blog.servername.com/blog. After that it worked for a while and stopped after a while and I've did some changes to the config which I cannot recall.

Comment: @TimoStark you were right, there was another option in the db that was referring to the old domain. Thanks!